# Identity minus a matrix times its transpose positive semidefinite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is it possible to characterize $I-A^TA\succeq 0$ in terms of the elements of $A$? ($I$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix, $A$ is $m\times n$ and $\succeq 0$ means that the resulting matrix is positive semidefinite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really a good characterization in terms of the entries.  What we **can** say is that the [singular values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) of $A$ are all less than $1$.

In other words, for any vector $x$, we have $\|Ax\| \leq \|x\|$.

Comment: Many thanks. I would like to understand a bit more about why not though - perhaps you could give me a reference? Are we at least able to simulate such matrices A from the feasible space?

Comment: A reasonable way to produce such matrices is via singular value decomposition.  In particular, take a diagonal matrix $\Sigma$ with diagonal entries $\sigma_i$ with $0 \leq \sigma_i \leq 1$.  Produce orthogonal matrices $U$ and $V$, then take $A = U\Sigma V$.  Notably, $\Sigma$ might be a non-square diagonal matrix.

Comment: Alternatively: if you can numerically calculate $\sigma_1(B) = \|B\|$ (certainly possible with most math software packages), then it suffices to feed in a (random) matrix $B$ and take $A = B/\sigma_1(B)$.

Comment: I do not have a reference that directly answers your question of "why can't you characterize this in terms of the entries of $A$".  Technically, I'm not saying that you *can't*, I'm saying that there's no nice way to do so.  The required calculation is tantamount to extracting the largest eigenvalue from $A^TA$.